# Fix incorrectly encoded JSON data

Tags: php, json

I was trying to fix some data up for a client and have instead broken it further by json_encoding already json_encoded data and ending up with a database filled with unusable strings.

One such broken string looks like this

```
"[{\"datum_von\":\"2012\",\"datum_bis\":\"2012\",\"organisation\":\"A s.r.o., školící středisko pro vrcholný management\",\"hauptfaecher\":\"Top management\"},{\"datum_von\":\"2011\",\"datum_bis\":\"2011\",\"organisation\":\"Goethe Institut\",\"hauptfaecher\":\"Německý jazyk\r\n\"}]"
```

Any tips on fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: "It's now 2:45am and I would very much like assistance fixing this."  Yeah, well, that's irrelevant here.  If you have some sort of rush job, you should hire a consultant.  Stack Overflow is a place where people can share questions and answers, where everyone can learn from everyone.  Anything outside of that context (such as oh-please-hurry-it's-3AM) is irrelevant.

Comment: It's not a rush job, I just can't sleep while a thing is broken and was appealing to people's generosity and pity.

Comment: No need, we'll help you or not, regardless of the circumstances of the problem.

Comment: Can you paste exactly what the data is, and use a code block instead of `>`?  It isn't clear from your question whether or not these line breaks are in there.

Comment: that's not a broken json, that's just escaped string

Comment: @line88 No, there are issues with the line breaks.  This is more than just a double-escaping issue.

Comment: just google - jsonlint

Comment: @Healyhatman Just roll back to a backup from before you did this?

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I'd love to roll back but apparently 8 users have filled in the form since the last backup and each entry has 4 massive pages of stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you double `json_encoded` why not just try double `json_decoding` ? It works for me - the only issue is the C&P I did from your quoted code contains a \n\r at the end, which breaks the json.  Once those 2 are removed, it works fine.

Your json -

```
"[{\"datum_von\":\"2012\",\"datum_bis\":\"2012\",\"organisation\":\"A s.r.o., školící středisko pro vrcholný management\",\"hauptfaecher\":\"Top management\"},{\"datum_von\":\"2011\",\"datum_bis\":\"2011\",\"organisation\":\"Goethe Institut\",\"hauptfaecher\":\"Německý jazyk\"}]"
```

Saved as "e.json" .. substitute a DB read.

```
<?php
$j=file_get_contents("e.json");

print_r(json_decode(json_decode($j)));

?>
```

Gives

```
ivan@darkstar:~$ php e.php
PHP Fatal error:  sodium_init() in Unknown on line 0
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [datum_von] => 2012
            [datum_bis] => 2012
            [organisation] => A s.r.o., školící středisko pro vrcholný management
            [hauptfaecher] => Top management
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [datum_von] => 2011
            [datum_bis] => 2011
            [organisation] => Goethe Institut
            [hauptfaecher] => Německý jazyk
        )

)
```

Read your records in - if the double `json_decode` doesn't return a bool `false` then re-encode a single time and send back to the server and update that record.

Comment: Removing the \r\n is fine for one entry, but what about removing it from an arbitrary number of entries?

Comment: @Healyhatman `str_replace()` should do it for you.  There is even an example of it in the PHP manual that shows how to replace \n\r, \n and \r in one fell swoop, and in the proper order.  Assuming you've fixed it so you aren't still entering double encoded data, fixing a few records manually (your OP said you had 8 ...) isn't that hard to do.

Comment: I used str_replace to replace \r\n with a ridiculous string, and if double json_decoded and if it was not null, did a single decode, put the \r\n back and returned that.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in php use function stripslashes()
Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php for more details on function.

It will remove the slashes from the Json object.

Comment: There are line breaks in there and it turns them into rn

Comment: First remove lines breaks from your string using
preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $yourString );